# How to distinguish between adjective and adverb used as to-infinitive?

Tags: adjectives, adverbs, to-infinitive

For example,

> 1. Both managers and staff benefit from the workshops designed by a psychological institute ***to improve*** relationships within the workplace.
> 2. Sync Online has delivered copies of contracts to all the parties who have agreed to participate in a new venture ***to offer*** music on the Internet.

In my book's manual, to-infinitive used in 1. (*to improve*) is adverb, and used in 2. (*to offer*) is adjective. How to distinguish between adjective and adverb used as to-infinitive like these sentences?

Comment: I'd avoid the terms 'adverb' and 'adjective' here. The _to-_ infinitival clause in your first example is a purpose adjunct - it gives the purpose of the design of the workshops. In the second, it is an infinitival relative clause modifying "new venture". Like many infinitival relatives, it has a modal meaning comparable to that expressed by "can or "should", cf. "... a new venture that can offer music on the Internet".

Comment: @BillJ Why isn't it considered that "to improve" in first example modify "a psychological institute"?

Comment: Because it does not identify, or add anything to (or delimit) the meaning of the noun phrase "psychological institute". Instead, it gives the purpose of the workshops which were designed by a psychological institute in order to improve relationships ...". In very simple terms, you could think of the infinitival clause as modifying the verb "designed".

Comment: @BillJ I still don't understand... Why don't this "institute" be considered "tool" or "form" or other nouns modified by to-infinitives in JavaLatte's answer? What is different?

Comment: @Orient The difference is only made clear from the context. There is nothing in the sentence structure that explicitly shows that this is a different use of the *to-* infinitive. Native speakers (and sufficiently advanced nonnative speakers) understand that it is unlikely that a psychological institute was founded for the purpose of improving relations in the workplace. What is more likely is a psychological institute that has the knowledge and skills to design workshops such that they improve relationships in the workplace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both of these sentences use a to-infinitive to express purpose, use or capability. The only difference between them is that one applies to a verb and the other to a noun.

The verb form is quite common, for example:

> I am going out **to post some letters**

The noun use is widely documented for [abstract nouns](http://www.grammaring.com/noun-phrase-to-infinitive) like ability, need etc, but there is less information about its use with concrete nouns. Words like tool, company and venture can clearly be associated with a purpose:

> My Swiss Army Knife has a tool **to take stones out of horses' hooves**

There are many other possible usages, though:

> This is the form **to apply for a visa.**
>   I have some money **to buy an ice cream**
>   I need a new dress **to wear at the wedding**

While these sentences are examples of to-infinitives applied to nouns and verbs, the terms adverb and adjective are, as BillJ says, inappropriate and misleading.